# Function in R for validating existence of specific columns on a data.frame

Tags: r, validation, dataframe

I'd like to validate that a `data.frame` contains columns with specific names.  Ideally this would be a utility function that I can just pass the `data.frame` and expected column names and the function will raise an error if the `data.frame` does not contain the expected columns.  I have written my own function below, however, this seems like something that would already exist in the R ecosystem.

My questions are:

1. Does such a function (or one-liner) already exist either in base R or in a common package?
2. If not, any suggestions for my function (below)?

Example of the function I have written to do this:

```
validate_df_columns <- function(df, columns) {
    chr_df <- deparse(substitute(df))
    chr_columns <- paste(columns, collapse = ", ")
    if (!('data.frame' %in% class(df))) {
        stop(paste("Argument", df, "must be a data.frame."))
    }
    if (sum(colnames(df) %in% columns) != length(columns)) {
        stop(paste(chr_df, "must contain the columns", chr_columns))
    }
}

validate_df_columns(data.frame(a=1:3, b=4:6), c("a", "b", "c'"))
## Error in validate_df_columns(data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6), c("a", "b",  : 
##   data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6) must contain the columns a, b, c'
```

Answer (score 5):

The packages `tibble` and `rlang`, part of `tidyverse` have a function to check this :

```
library(tibble) # or library(rlang) or library(tidyverse)
has_name(iris, c("Species","potatoe"))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Technically it lives in `rlang` and its code is just :

```
function (x, name) 
{
    name %in% names2(x)
}
```

where `rlang::names2` is an enhanced version of `base::names` which returns a vector of empty strings rather than `NULL` when the object doesn't have names.

Here's a way to rewrite your function :

```
validate_df_columns <- function(df, columns){
if (!is.data.frame(df)) {
    stop(paste("Argument", deparse(substitute(df)), "must be a data.frame."))
}
  if(!all(i <- rlang::has_name(df,columns)))
    stop(sprintf(
      "%s doesn't contain: %s",
      deparse(substitute(df)),
      paste(columns[!i], collapse=", ")))
}

validate_df_columns(iris, c("Species","potatoe","banana"))
# Error in validate_df_columns(iris, c("Species", "potatoe", "banana")) : 
# iris doesn't contain: potatoe, banana
```

Using `deparse(substitute(...))` here makes little sense to me though, as it's not used interactively, clearer in my opinion to just say `"df"`.

Answer (score 0):

The `%in%` operator works with pairs of vectors, so there is already a one-liner we can use here.  Consider:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1:3), b=c(4:6), c=c(7:9))
names <- c("a", "c", "blah", "doh")
names[names %in% names(df)]

[1] "a" "c"
```

If you want to assert that the data frame contains all the input names, then just use:

```
length(names %in% names(df)) == length(names)     # to check all inputs are present
length(names %in% names(df)) == length(names(df)) # to check that input matches df
```

Comment: Thanks, based on your code, I think what I'm actually looking for is `sum(names %in% names(df)) == length(names)`.  This would return false is there are names within `names` that do not exist as columns.

Comment: You might also want to check for duplicates using `unique`.